# Splitting date to quarter hour

Tags: sql, impala

I have a requirement where in I would need to convert two records which will have time which spans for one full day (24 hour period).

```
Eg : Record 1 - Time from 3:00 Am to 12:59:59 PM
     Record 2 - Time from 00:00 AM to 2:59:59 AM
```

The table structure is

```
 start_time         | end_time            |local_start_time     |local_endtime |
 2015-01-01 3:00:00 | 2015-01-01 23:59:59 |  2015-01-01 4:00:00 | 2015-02-01 01:59:59
 2015-02-01 12:00:00| 2015-02-01 2:59:59  | 2015-02-01 13:00:00 |2015-02-01 3:59:59
```

From such two records i need to create 96 records within the period of 24hours. Each record should be a for a quarter hour.

```
 Eg:
 start_time         |     end_time      |local_start_time   |local_endtime    | Quarter_hour
 2015-01-01 3:00:00 | 2015-01-01 3:14:59|2015-01-01 4:00:00 | 2015-01-01 4:14:59 | 1
 2015-01-01 3:15:00 | 2015-01-01 3:29:59|2015-01-01 4:15:00 | 2015-01-01 4:29:59 | 2
```

and so on till Quarter_hour becomes 96 for each 1 day period.

I am not sure on how to implement this. Any help would be really useful. Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Unfortunately many dbms products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time...)

Answer (score 0):

Sincerely, I never have been working with Impala, but if I would like do it only with SQL sentences.. my approach could be the following:

I need quarters per hours:

```
select '00:00' qstart, '14:59' qend union
select '15:00' qstart, '29:59' qend union
select '30:00' qstart, '44:59' qend union
select '45:00' qstart, '59:59' qend
```

And I need hours! (Do you have some alternative to Oralce CONNECT clausule?):

```
select '00' hhour, 1 ordinal union
select '01' hhour, 2 ordinal union
select '02' hhour, 3 ordinal union
select '03' hhour, 4 ordinal union
select '04' hhour, 5 ordinal union
select '05' hhour, 6 ordinal union
select '06' hhour, 7 ordinal union
select '07' hhour, 8 ordinal union
select '08' hhour, 9 ordinal union
select '09' hhour, 10 ordinal union
select '10' hhour, 11 ordinal union
select '11' hhour, 12 ordinal union
select '12' hhour, 13 ordinal union
select '13' hhour, 14 ordinal union
select '14' hhour, 15 ordinal union
select '15' hhour, 16 ordinal union
select '16' hhour, 17 ordinal union
select '17' hhour, 18 ordinal union
select '18' hhour, 19 ordinal union
select '19' hhour, 20 ordinal union
select '20' hhour, 21 ordinal union
select '21' hhour, 22 ordinal union
select '22' hhour, 23 ordinal union
select '23' hhour, 24 ordinal
```

If you make a join with these 2 sentences...

```
select hhour || ':' || qstart as hqstart, hhour || ':' || qend as hqend, ordinal
from
(select '00' hhour, 1 ordinal union
select '01' hhour, 2 ordinal union
select '02' hhour, 3 ordinal union
select '03' hhour, 4 ordinal union
select '04' hhour, 5 ordinal union
select '05' hhour, 6 ordinal union
select '06' hhour, 7 ordinal union
select '07' hhour, 8 ordinal union
select '08' hhour, 9 ordinal union
select '09' hhour, 10 ordinal union
select '10' hhour, 11 ordinal union
select '11' hhour, 12 ordinal union
select '12' hhour, 13 ordinal union
select '13' hhour, 14 ordinal union
select '14' hhour, 15 ordinal union
select '15' hhour, 16 ordinal union
select '16' hhour, 17 ordinal union
select '17' hhour, 18 ordinal union
select '18' hhour, 19 ordinal union
select '19' hhour, 20 ordinal union
select '20' hhour, 21 ordinal union
select '21' hhour, 22 ordinal union
select '22' hhour, 23 ordinal union
select '23' hhour, 24 ordinal) Hours,
(select '00:00' qstart, '14:59' qend union
select '15:00' qstart, '29:59' qend union
select '30:00' qstart, '44:59' qend union
select '45:00' qstart, '59:59' qend ) Quarters order by ordinal, qstart
```

You have all 96 records what you want!

```
hqstart     hqend       ordinal
00:00:00    00:14:59    1
00:15:00    00:29:59    1
00:30:00    00:44:59    1
00:45:00    00:59:59    1
01:00:00    01:14:59    2
01:15:00    01:29:59    2
01:30:00    01:44:59    2
01:45:00    01:59:59    2
...         ...         .
```

Then if you want select the quartes between 2 times... let's say.. quarters from 14:09:00 to 15:06:30:

```
select * from 
(
select hhour || ':' || qstart as hqstart, hhour || ':' || qend as hqend, ordinal
from
   (select '00' hhour, 1 ordinal union
    select '01' hhour, 2 ordinal union
    select '02' hhour, 3 ordinal union
    select '03' hhour, 4 ordinal union
    select '04' hhour, 5 ordinal union
    select '05' hhour, 6 ordinal union
    select '06' hhour, 7 ordinal union
    select '07' hhour, 8 ordinal union
    select '08' hhour, 9 ordinal union
    select '09' hhour, 10 ordinal union
    select '10' hhour, 11 ordinal union
    select '11' hhour, 12 ordinal union
    select '12' hhour, 13 ordinal union
    select '13' hhour, 14 ordinal union
    select '14' hhour, 15 ordinal union
    select '15' hhour, 16 ordinal union
    select '16' hhour, 17 ordinal union
    select '17' hhour, 18 ordinal union
    select '18' hhour, 19 ordinal union
    select '19' hhour, 20 ordinal union
    select '20' hhour, 21 ordinal union
    select '21' hhour, 22 ordinal union
    select '22' hhour, 23 ordinal union
    select '23' hhour, 24 ordinal) Hours,
   (select '00:00' qstart, '14:59' qend union
    select '15:00' qstart, '29:59' qend union
    select '30:00' qstart, '44:59' qend union
    select '45:00' qstart, '59:59' qend ) Quarters order by ordinal
) AllQuarters
where (hqstart >= '14:09:00' and hqstart < '15:06:30') or
      (hqend  >=  '14:09:00' and hqend   < '15:06:30')
order by ordinal, hqstart, hqend;
```

Output:

```
hqstart     hqend       ordinal
14:00:00    14:14:59    15
14:15:00    14:29:59    15
14:30:00    14:44:59    15
14:45:00    14:59:59    15
15:00:00    15:14:59    16
```

You can find a SQL Fiddle example [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/6201)

Take care with `from dual` clause in this example, it's only for ORACLE dbms.